# What is this Google Backup and Sync "Back up your files" dialog asking?

Tags: google-apps, google-sync

Google Drive recently became Google Backup and Sync, and this dialog started occasionally popping out of its menu bar item:

[image]

I don't have a "Boot OS X" folder that I'm aware of, in Google Drive or locally. When I look at the settings for Google Backup and Sync, I don't see anything about this. I haven't touched the settings since it was Google Drive, so it's set to sync my Google Drive and nothing more.

I can't tell what the files are from the little generic icons, and I can't figure out how to get a list. It's also not clear what device it's talking about, or what choice it's going to remember (since the options are essentially "yes" or "later").

Does anyone know what this dialog is about and what I might have done to cause it?

Comment: And backup and sync is now Google Drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an encrypted Time Machine backup disk, there is a hidden `Boot OS X` partition located on it that contains a recovery OS, allowing you to decrypt and boot from the backup in case you need to restore it from scratch. You can see this partition if you run `diskutil list` from the command line:

```
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Time Machine            4.0 TB     disk3s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk3s3
```

Time Machine will occasionally mount this partition while making a backup. It looks like Backup and Sync thinks this is a normal external USB drive and offers to sync it, which I suspect is a bug.

Comment: I don't have a Time Machine backup disk, encrypted or otherwise. I do use FileVault encryption on my internal drive, so perhaps that's it. In any case I haven't seen that message since around the time I posted the question in 2017, so I assume Google has fixed whatever issue was causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have no "Boot OS X" folder now, but if you backup these files to cloud, there will be such a folder containing these files.
The most probably cause of this dialog is due to the update from old Google Drive to new Backup and Sync changed your source settings automatically though you didn't do by yourself. Thus, better check out your current settings to find out. If it is what i guess, then uncheck the related source folder will terminate such dialog.
Best wishes!

Comment: I re-checked my settings and, as I said in the question, it is set to sync my Google Drive and nothing more. All the local sources are unchecked.

Comment: Then, did you recently add some files into your Google Drive folder?

Comment: No new files that I'm aware of.

Comment: Is there any external devices connected to your computer when this dialog pops up sin you said it exists occasionally? If not, then i can't figure out the real cause. Maybe you can try to click "BACK UP" to let them be synced to cloud and check out what they really are there.

Comment: No external devices connected.